# Connection to backend cannot be established when firewall is up. Need help setting up Nginx to allow UDP

Tags: nginx, udp, port, firewall, ubuntu-22.04

I'm building a multiplayer game using [Geckos.io](https://github.com/geckosio/geckos.io) which runs on UDP.

I have deployed the server on a Ubuntu droplet from digital ocean.
I have setup and configured nginx, added TLS using certbot. Everything seems to be working fine until I enable the firewall.

```
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

I'm sharing a deployment instruction found on the Readme of [geckos](https://github.com/geckosio/geckos.io#deployment) framework.

> You have to make sure you deploy it to a server which forwards all traffic on ports 9208/tcp (or another port you define) and 0-65535/udp to your application.
>
> Port 9208/tcp (or another port you define) is used for the peer signaling. The peer connection itself will be on a random port between 0-65535/udp.

Here's the nginx config for the game backend server (actual domain name changed to my_domain)

```
server {
    server_name my_domain;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;  #port should be same as the one the app is listening on
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
        proxy_send_timeout 86400s;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_domain/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_domain/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = my_domain) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name my_domain;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

`The peer connection itself will be on a random port between 0-65535/udp.`
I don't know how to forward all the UDP ports needed by the framework.
Should I enable the ports on firewall? If so how?
What changes should I make on nginx to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously I tried to open the firewall using UFW

```
sudo ufw allow 0:65535/udp
```

This always resulted in Bad Port error.
Upon further study, I found out that we can't use port 0 as it is considered a virtual port. Hence changing the command to the following solved the issue for me.

```
sudo ufw allow 1025:65535/udp
```

It is not safe to use port ranging from 0-1023 as it is intended for system use. Hence updated the answer to allow ports from 1025:65535